# Can´t convert a list with sublists that have 2 elements in each of them to a single string

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I need to convert a list with sublists that have 2 elements in each of them to a single string

What I have:

```
[['A','B'],['C','D']]
```

What´s what I want to be converted to:

```
"ABCD"
```

I tried this:

```
list=[['A','B'],['C','D']]

hello=""

for i in list:

     hello=hello+i

print (hello)
```

Says that I have a TypeError, and I can´t understand why.

Answer (score 4):

You have a list of iterable so as a pythonic way, use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to flatten your list then join the characters with `str.join()` method:

```
In [12]: from itertools import chain

In [13]: lst = [['A','B'],['C','D']]

In [14]: ''.join(chain.from_iterable(lst))
Out[14]: 'ABCD'
```

Here is a benchmark against using two `join`, which shows that the `itertools` approach is **2+ times faster**:

```
In [19]: %timeit ''.join(chain.from_iterable(lst))
10000 loops, best of 3: 114 µs per loop

In [20]: %timeit ''.join(''.join(w) for w in lst)
1000 loops, best of 3: 250 µs per loop
```

Comment: I guess, if we talk about measurements, `from itertools import chain` also should be considered and timed. Like `setup` argument for `timeit.Timer` module: `timeit.Timer('a=s[:]; ', setup='import random; s = [random.random() for i in range(1000)]')`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest It doesn't make much difference since it only happens one time. And is easily negligible.

Comment: agreed, using `itertools.chain` would be faster, anyway

Answer (score 3):

> Says that I have a TypeError, and I can´t understand why

The error you got is pretty verbose: *TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly*, that means that you can't implicitly concatenate a list object with a string object like `[1,2] + "hello"`

On the other hand, you can concatenate lists, and in your simple case this `''.join(list[0]+list[1])` will also give the expected result `ABCD`

Use `str.join(iterable)` function(or join with `itertools.chain.from_iterable` function which should go faster):

```
l = [['A','B'],['C','D']]
hello = ''.join(''.join(w) for w in l)

print(hello)
```

The output:

```
ABCD
```

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
sampleData = [['A','B'],['C','D']]
output = "".join( "".join(i) for i in sampleData)
print (output)
```

or

```
sampleData = [['A','B'],['C','D']]
output = ""
for i in sampleData:
    output += "".join(i)
print (output)
```

output

```
ABCD
```

The error you are getting becouse you are trying to add a list and a string

Answer (score 2):

You can do it while only calling `str.join()` once and using a list comprehension:

```
''.join([char for element in [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']] for char in element])
```

Outputs:

```
'ABCD'
```

Answer (score 0):

The TypeError results from your operation to add the sublist *i* to the string *hello*. I believe this is because the operation is not supported between the type list and str, as can be seen in the following examples:

```
['a', 'b']+'2'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

'2'+['a', 'b']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

There are various answers above which recommend alternative code and use the "join" method. However I though I'd include an alternative, which uses purely loops:

```
l = [['A','B'],['C','D']]

hello = ""
for sublist in l:
    for element in sublist:
        hello += str(element)
print(hello)
```

Note this is probably slower than other methods.
In addition I recommend against using "list" as a variable name, as it is already used by the class.